# Переключение языков, перенаправление на страницу

Tags: asp.net-mvc

На сайте есть переключение языков,
в `HomeController` прописываю

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{

// Validate input
        culture = CultureHelper.GetValidCulture(culture);

        // Save culture in a cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Co okies["_culture"];
        if (cookie != null)
            cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
        else
        {

            cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cookie.HttpOnly = false; // Not accessible by JS.
            cookie.Value = culture;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        }
        Response.Co okies.Add(cookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

так как я в конце прописываю `RedirectToAction("Index");` то получается, что на какой бы странице не использовался переключатель языков, всегда потом идет перенаправление на Главную.
Как прописать так, чтобы перенаправление шло на ту же страницу, с которой был получен запрос?

Как понимаю, надо использовать `Request.UrlReferrer`, но не могу разобраться как?

Если я прописываю

```
string urlReferrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction(urlReferrer);
```

то при использовании переключалки языков выдается ошибка
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос снимается, заработало с

```
string urlReferrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            return Redirect(urlReferrer);
```